# Validating DataGrid data when bound directly to a DataTable - C#/WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataTable which I bind to a DataGrid in WPF. No column generation is done in the XAML, everything is done when I create the DataTable in code.

I have 2 way binding, so the user can update the values in the DataGrid and it will update the DataTable, although this is not an event I can see when debugging, my results show it works as intended.

However if the type of a column is say double and the user enters text, the existing DataTable data for that cell is preserved, the cell is outlined in red and my debugger output shows a FormatException occurred.

What I am wanting to do is be able to either:

a) Handle this exception and show a warning to the user in my UI

b) Have some custom validation method which can set a flag in my code that I can use to handle the error at some point

I don't mind which solution I go with, I just don't want the user to not notice the error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna stay with ado.net and datatables then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1120xds5.aspx

EDIT:

```
  this.MyTable.ColumnChanging += MyTableColumnChangingStuff;

    private void MyTableColumnChangingStuff(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Column.ColumnName == "MyColumnTestName")
        {
           var errormsg = MyValidateTestNameMethod(e.ProposedValue);
           e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Column.ColumnName, errormsg);
        }
        //...
    }
```

EDIT 2:

> Thanks, just given that a try and while the event does get called when
>   I modify my data of the correct type, it does not get called if the
>   datatype the user inputs is wrong. The same as before happens, the box
>   is highlighted red and the format exception is handled by wpf, but the
>   event isn't called.

thats true. and there are just 2 solution for me. first create behaviors for your input controls where you can make sure that the values ALWAYS convertible to your underlying type. another solution would be thats your viewmodel where you bind to just have properties of type string. the nice thing with this is - that you never get a bindingexception because of casting a type. and what you have to do now is to implement IDataErrorInfo where you check your string property. and of course you have to cast your string values to the right type when you go to your model.

till now i use the first approach because i use datepicker, numeric behaviors and dont have any other types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am unable to follow that as I do not have any datasets to open in dataset designer. I create and populate my bound datatable in the instance of the class I need it for.

Comment: you dont need a designer. you simple use the DataTable.ColumnChanging event. there you can set your Validation rules with SetColumnError. see my edit

Comment: Thanks, just given that a try and while the event does get called when I modify my data of the correct type, it does not get called if the datatype the user inputs is wrong. The same as before happens, the box is highlighted red and the format exception is handled by wpf, but the event isn't called.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone with the latter suggestion and it is working now.